# Using the Firebase auto-generated noreply email with Cloud Functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am developing a mobile app using Firebase as a backend. My app is only going to be available to students of a specific school, so I need to identify their identity BEFORE creating their account (so you couldn't use your friend's school ID or whatever). To achieve this, I send emails with verification codes before their Firebase user is created.

I wrote a Cloud Function in Typescript using `nodemailer` to send emails, and it works perfectly. However, it is currently using my personal gmail account that owns the Firebase project:

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
      user: 'myfirebaseaccount@gmail.com',
      pass: 'myfirebasepassword'
  }
})
```

I saw that Firebase Auth uses a noreply email like `noreply@myapp.firebaseapp.com` for account verfication, password resetting, and other stuff. [See Firebase Auth screenshot... (in Spanish btw)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHR7q.png)

However, I haven't found a way to make this email work, obviously because I don't know the password, or if it has any. I tried to use this noreply email with my firebase account password with no luck:

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
      user: 'noreply@myapp.firebaseapp.com',
      pass: 'myfirebasepassword'
  }
})
```

```
Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials d7sm947636oic.46 - gsmtp
```

This is the same error I got before I activated the use of "non-secure" apps on my personal gmail account.

So in summary, I don't know how can I activate this feature on this noreply, or how to know the actual password of this email, or what do I have to change or do to send emails using this account, or even if using this email address is possible at all. I haven't found any documentation or info regarding this topic.

Comment: Hi there! Did you manage to solve that problem? I also would like to use that noreply email in my Firebase project.

Comment: Hello! Sadly, no. At the time I asked on the Firebase subreddit too and there I was told that Gmail has a special filter that changes the "from" field of emails that differ from the account's email address.

I haven't checked since then but it's not very likely that changed tbh. I didn't continue with that project, but if I did I would probably go with a custom email service in one of their free tiers (if you can find one haha). I hope it helps.